# Delete project template in Rider

Tags: rider, project-template

The picture is pretty explanatory, I am trying to remove the project template from the "Other" category, but I cannot locate any useful setting/configuration anywhere. The places I have looked into are in:

- %APPDATA%\JetBrains\Rider<version>,
- %LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Rider<version> and
- %USERPROFILE%\.templateengine

The reason I want to achieve this is because I cannot add a new template to the dialogue.
Any insights?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved the problem myself. It turns out that according to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-63806) post, currently (25 Jun 2021), support to .NET 6 is limited. I had also installed the Visual Studio 2022 Preview on my system which ships with .NET 6 SDK and that caused the endless "syncing" issue. Good times.